# CKEdtior not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate CKEditor into a MVC application. As far as I can tell all I should really have to do is.

Add the following to my master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Then on my view itself. I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function() { $('#news').ckeditor(); });
</script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <%=Html.TextBox("title")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("title", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="news">News:</label>
            <%=Html.TextArea("news")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("news", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="publishedDate">Publication Date:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("publishedDate") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("publishedDate", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
```

Please bear in mind I am not trying to get this to actually DO anything postback wise. Just to actually render in the first place. Can someone point out exactly what it is I am doing wrong?

Oh and if it helps any VS is also giving me the following warning:

> Warning   1   Error updating JScript IntelliSense: ..Cut to Protect the
>   innocent..\ckeditor\ckeditor.js: 'getFirst()' is null or not an object
>   @ 15:180  ..Cut to Protect the
>   innocent..\Views\Shared\Admin.Master  1   1   ilaTraining

Answer (score 1):

With the line `$('.test').ckeditor();` you try to apply the ckeditor to the elements which has the css class `.test`. But in your view none of the inputs have this class.

Assuming that you want to make your `TextArea` into an ckeditor so you need to add the class with [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493070%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
<%= Html.TextArea("news", new { @class = ".test" }) %>
```

Or you can reference your TextArea also by the id "news" (because this is the id what you gave to your input with the expression `Html.TextArea("news")`). So the following code also should work:

```
$('#news').ckeditor();
```

Because you are trying to use the jQuery adapter of the ckeditor **you have to make sure that you load the ckeditor after jQuery is loaded**. So the correct order of the script includes should be the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js %>"></script>
```

As a side note: you should use the `Url.Content` helper when you include scripts or css when using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: My bad. The $('.test').ckeditor();  did actually say "news". I just changed it while trying something else and never changed it back. Still doesn't work I am affraid. Although I will use the Url.Content bit as advised.

Comment: Then it should be `$('#news').ckeditor();` if you are referencing the id of the element.

Comment: @user1708468 then as I wrote in my answer with the correct id selector syntax: `$('#news').ckeditor();` should work.

Comment: That still doesn't work. I am sure this is just trying to tick me off :-) Thanks for the help. It shouldn't make any difference that my master page is stored in another directory? I am almost 100% positive it shouldn't as you get to the same location using either url...but I have been looking at this that long....

Comment: @user1708468 the order of the script files in important. Try this first line should be `Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js` then `ckeditor/ckeditor.js` and then `ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js `

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the element by id, you should use `#`, such as `$('#news').ckeditor();`

See the difference in the jQuery API for [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at:

Try without using the jQuery adapter just to see if the editor loads.

Remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

Replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function() { $('#news').ckeditor(); });
</script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function() { CKEDITOR.replace( 'news' ); });
</script>
```

---

There were a couple of releases of the jQuery adapter that had bugs, maybe try a different CKEditor version?

---

You could try using a more recent version of jQuery. The version that you're using ( jquery-1.3.2 ), was released in February of 2009. It's 3 1/2 years old.

---

Does the problem occur in all browsers?